# 2 Ip's one address?

Tags: java

This is program that shows the ip for requested website: 
    {

```
 import java.net.*;
 class verify {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException{
   InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   System.out.println(address);
   address=InetAddress.getByName("www.bcetgsp.ac.in");
   System.out.println(address);
   InetAddress SW[]=InetAddress.getAllByName("www.nba.com");
   for(int i=0;i<SW.length;i++) 
    System.out.println(SW[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

here i get 2 ip's for nba.com

What is the reason for this?
what i have heard is"it is common for a single name to be used to represent several machines."But if we go by this and replace www.nba.com by www.google.com,i get only 1 ip.(why?)

Comment: It's called DNS resolution. A name can be resolved to multiple addresses. `InetAddress.getByName(String)` simply returns the 1st address returned by `InetAddress.getAllByName`. Wikipedia's article on DNS is ok (just checked): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: Also See [Does every domain has a unique IP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5390618/617750)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: a DNS record can be mapped to a number of IPs for redundancy (**fault tolerance**) reasons.

It means that lots of servers answer for nba.com. It's normal.

#### Why does www.google.com return only one answer?

Well, I'm unsure... Google definitely doesn't have one single server to answer your queries (otherwise they won't be 24/7 online with highest availability), but I have a possible explanation.

I remember that www.google.com points to multiple CNAME records, each one resolving to 1 final IP address. Probably, www.nba.com is directly mapped to several IPs (2 in your case, too few for such an important website).

Comment: *Why does www.google.com return only one answer?* mostly b/c it doesn't: Test it yourself before writing the answer.  But also it can depend on the requster and even one would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's because they have server farm over there. One name can be shared across many IPs, which are selected in a round robin fashion upon each DNS request.

Answer (score 0):

Google records don't return only 1 ip:

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 74.125.230.84
google.com has address 74.125.230.83
google.com has address 74.125.230.80
google.com has address 74.125.230.81
google.com has address 74.125.230.82
```

Comment: DNS can depend on the requester and it may return results based on the region.

Comment: Yep, but I intented to show that there can also be more than 2 IP.

Comment: now i am getting multiple ip's for google.But earlier i got only one. what is the reason for this?

Comment: I have the same behaviour, but reversed! Now I only have one IP for google. Why? Because my local DNS didn't know the IP for google.com, so it queried his referal DNS and asked for google, then forwarded me the result. But it also keepd the first record in cache. An other important point with that is TTL (Time To Live) in the DNS protocol.

Comment: @Aif what do u mean by " But it also keepd the first record in cache. "

Comment: I mean "it kept the first ..", sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast), a host may only have a single IP address in DNS but may be handled by physically many machines spread out over the globe. So, even though the *usual* answer for providing fault tolerance and load balancing is through [DNS round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) or [geo-location](http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/browser/trunk/pdns/modules/geobackend/README), using Anycast and smart [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP) routing can provide similar fault tolerance, load balancing, and network-topology appropriate routes.

Of course, Anycast is best suited to stateless tasks, such as DNS lookups; it *can* be used to provide TCP services, but systems requiring stored per-client state on servers may not be optimum, as clients may connect to different servers as routing topology changes. Without Anycast, the routes might just be non-optimal to the endpoint, but still function. (A better route to a different host may exist: with Anycast, packets will be redirected. Without Anycast, packets will take the slower route to the already-established but less-good peer.)